# How do I open a file with the new VS2022 code search?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

For years, I've used `<ctrl>+,` to find files and open them. Now, this opens a 'Code search' window, which find the file, but I then can't work out how to open it in the editor. If I hit return or double-click I get a popup which says "The document ... is already open. Do you want to close it?" and whether I click [Yes] or [No] the window closes and the file does *NOT* open!

How do I search by filename and open the file?

-- update:

I have no files open.

I type '+,' and type a partial filename.

I double-click the one I want and get...

[image: screenshot]

Then, whether I click Yes or No, the code search window closes!

Comment: Why not set Ctrl+, to open find files window again? Also for me files are properly opened when clicked on in the new search window.

Comment: FWIW, I encountered similar issues, and I'm not able to repro them after upgrading VS2022 from 17.6 to 17.6.2. Could be a coincidence though.

Comment: I also encounter this only on .net frameworks webform project with aspx files.  Tried repairing vs and still no luck.  Did you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the preview, when you disable it, it works. Waiting a solution from Microsoft.

[image: Location of the preview buttons]